# Architecture of SQL tables

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

I am wondering is it more useful and practical (size of DB) to create multiple tables in sql with two columns (one column containing foreign key and one column containing random data) or merge it and create one table containing multiple columns. I am asking this because in my scenario one product holding primary key could have sufficient/applicable data for only one column while other columns would be empty.

```
example a. one table
productID productname weight no_of_pages
1         book        130     500
2         watch       50      null
3         ring        null    null

example b. three tables
productID productname
1         book       
2         watch      
3         ring       

productID weight
1         130   
2         50    

productID no_of_pages
1         500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-table approach is more "normal" (in database terms) because it avoids columns that commonly store NULLs.  It's also something of a pain in programming terms because you have to JOIN a bunch of tables to get your original entity back.

I suggest adopting a middle way.  Weight seems to be a property of most products, if not all (indeed, a ring has a weight even if small and you'll probably want to know it for shipping purposes), so I'd leave that in the Products table.  But number of pages applies only to a book, as do a slew of other unmentioned properties (author, ISBN, etc).  In this example, I'd use a Products table and a Books table.  The books table would *extend* the Products table in a fashion similar to class inheritance in object oriented program.

All book-specific properties go into the Books table, and you join only Products and Books to get a complete description of a book.

Comment: Thanks Larry, but don't you think it would be to complicated to have Books table, Rings table etc. ie. to extend all the information available to a certain product. And for example what if (over time) certain information because available for both Books and Rings but not for Watches. Should you put that info in products table or have duplicate columns in both Books and Watches table?

Comment: It depends on how many product categories might reasonably occur in your database.  I would try to design the system so that _most_ categories fit into the Products table without an extender.  For common information in more than one category, I'd have to make a judgement value whether it belonged 1) in the Products table, 2) duplicated in two extender tables or 3) in an intermediate extender between the Products table and the two other extender tables.

Comment: So that leads us to another question - should tables be created based on products or based on attributes or set of attributes (grouped by theme).

Comment: Based on products or product categories.  Your tables should reflect actual entities in your data model.

Answer (score 0):

I think this all depends on how the tables will be used. Maybe your examples are oversimplifying things too much but it seems to me that the first option should be good enough.

You'd really use the second example if you're going to be doing extremely CPU intensive stuff with the first table and will only need the second and third tables when more information about a product is needed.

If you're going to need the information in the second and third tables most times you query the table, then there's no reason to join over every time and you should just keep it in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest example a, in case there is a defined set of attributes for product, and an example c if you need variable number of attributes (new attributes keep coming every now and then) -

example c

```
productID productName
1         book
2         watch
3         ring

attrID productID attrType    attrValue
1      1         weight      130
2      1         no_of_pages 500
3      2         weight      50
```

The table structure you have shown in example b is not normalized - there will be separate id columns required in second and third tables, since productId will be an fk and not a pk.

Comment: This is the Entity Value Layout, and remember you can't spell evil without EVL.

Comment: Yep, but if the number of attributes are not fixed, then this is the best layout to go for. As I mentioned, example a is preferred if the number of attributes are known in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many rows you are expecting on your PRODUCTS table.  I would say that it would not make sense to normalize your tables to 3N in this case because product name, weight, and no_of_pages each describe the products.  If you had repeating data such as manufacturers, it would make more sense to normalize your tables at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the background (data model), there is no way to tell which variant is more "correct". both are fine in certain scenarios.

Comment: That is true, but what about the size of a database? Do tables tend to expand the size of database more then columns?

Answer (score 0):

You want three tables, full stop.  That's best because there's no chance of watches winding up with pages (no pun intended) and some books without.  If you normalize, the server works for you.  If you don't, you do the work instead, just not as well.  Up to you.

> I am asking this because in my scenario one product holding primary key could have sufficient/applicable data for only one column while other columns would be empty.

That's always true of nullable columns.  Here's the rule: a nullable column has an *optional relationship to the key*.  A nullable column can always be, and usually should be, in a separate table where it can be non-null.